# append existing record to a collection of an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an association like so:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contact_classifications
  has_many :classifications, through: :contact_classifications
end

class ContactClassification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :classification
end

class Classification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contact_classifications
  has_many :contacts, through: :contact_classifications
end
```

I have an existing contact and an existing classification. When I use the following code:

```
contact = Contact.find(id)
classification = Classification.find(1)
contact.classifications << classification
```

It inserts a record into the join table ContactClassification. I want to build the association between the two existing records without creating the join record until after the save is called on one of the records.

How can I achieve this?